# How do I paste multiple [sub-]nodes into CherryTree?

Tags: nodes, copy-paste, multiline, treenode

Using `CherryTree` from *Giuseppe Penone*, Version `0.99.45`.

I want to copy a text list of node names and past it (from the clipboard) into CherryTree as a list of sub-nodes under the selected node.

Example - I want to select and copy this text into my clipboard:

```
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3
```

and then I want to paste in into my CherryTree file such that they become child nodes to the root node, like so:

```
Root Node
  |
  +-Child 1
  |
  +-Child 2
  |
  +-Child 3
```

Is there a way to do this simply in CherryTree?
I can't find anything that mentions it.